# Visual Studio 2022 - git add -u

Tags: git, visual-studio

How to do equivalent of `git add -u` - which adds all tracked changes. Currently I need to pick them manually from the gui and the revert button is scary close.

I know I can add `.gitignore` but I'm also curios if such option exists in the GUI - especially when Microsoft was so proud of it at one point IRC (for the new git interface).